# Construct a linear programming problem for which both the primal and the dual problem has no feasible solution

Tags: linear-programming

Construct (that is, find its coefficients) a linear programming problem with at most two variables and two restrictions, for which both the primal and the dual problem has no feasible solution.

---

For a linear programming problem to have no feasible solution it needs to be either unbounded or just not have a feasible region at all I think. Therefore, I know how I should construct a problem if it would only have to hold for the primal problem. However, could anyone tell me how I should find one for which both the primal and dual problem have no feasible solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $b=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)=-c$.  $Ax\ge b$ and $A^Ty\le c$ cannot both be satisfied with positive $x,y$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you please tell me though how you constructed this problem? What steps did you take to get to this?

Comment: First I tried to find a 1-d solution but I'm pretty sure there isn't one.  Then I tried to find a simple (diagonal) $A$ that works, which wasn't too hard to do.  One coordinate makes the primal infeasible, while the other makes the dual infeasible.

Comment: Upon rereading your answer I have an additional question; What are the objective functions that you use for both the primal and dual problem (I wasn't sure on how to exactly deduce that from your answer)?

Comment: @cruise, when a primal (or dual) region is empty, it is irrelevant which objective function is used.  However, when the primal *and*  dual constraints are specified, you can determine each objective function from the other.

Comment: Thank you for your help :). So if I understand correctly, every objective function can be used with the example that you gave?

Comment: @cruise, there is a relationship between the primal and dual regions. The $b$ is both the bound for the primal solution, and the objective function for the dual solution.  Similarly, the $c$ is both the bound for the dual solution and the objective function for the primal solution.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but I'm still not sure whether I fully understand your solution. Doesn't your dual problem boil down to the following: \begin{align} min \quad -y_1-y_2\\ s.t. \quad y_1\geq -1 \\ y_2\geq -1 \\ \end{align}? How is this dual problem infeasible?

Comment: Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/25601/73324 to understand the statements of the primal and dual problems.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an LP:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min \; & x_{1}+2 x_{2} \\
\text { s.t. } & x_{1}+x_{2}=1 \\
& 2 x_{1}+2 x_{2}=3
\end{aligned}
$$

and its dual:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\max\; & y_{1}+3 y_{2} \\
\text { s.t. } & y_{1}+2 y_{2}=1 \\
& y_{1}+2 y_{2}=2
\end{aligned}
$$

They are both infeasible.

Comment: why are they both infeasible?

Comment: Just try to solve the equations, and then you will find no solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is old and I think vadim123 already provided a senseful answer, but here's another solution:

the primal problem is
$$\min_{x}\; -1\text{x} \; \text{s.t.} \; 0\text{x} = 1$$

and the dual problem is

$$\max_{y} \; 1\text{y} \; \text{s.t.} \; 0\text{y} = -1$$

So you basically set $-c^T = b^T = 1 $ and $A = 0$.